# Как удалить из записей все переводы каретки на другую строку?

Tags: sql-server, sql

Здравствуйте. При вставке записей в текстовое поле таблицы SQL-сервера, текст копировали из MS Word. Некоторые вставки были с двумя или тремя строчками (перевод каретки). Вопрос:
Какой можно отправить запрос, чтобы удалить из записей все переводы каретки (сделать из двух строчек одну)?
*UPD1*:
И вместо перевода каретки поставить пробел.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я нашел ответ на вопрос. И он настолько удивителен и неординарен, что просто надо всем на это взглянуть!!!

Вот, собственно, в чем дело: я пробовал ставить разные символы как в `SQL Server Management Studio`, так и в `MS Access`. И результата не было. И тут стукнуло в голову не ставить никаких символов, а просто в запросе, в среде `MS Access`, открытие кавычки поставить на одной строке, а закрытие на другой. И О ЧУДО! Запрос прошел так, как мне надо было. Вот скриншот для более четкого понимания:

[image]

*UPD1*:
В `SQL Server Management Studio` также такой вариант работает.

Answer (score 0):

```
update  `mytable` set mytext_field=replace(mytext_field, '\r', ' ');
```

Comment: Не прокатило :( Вот мой запрос:  
    UPDATE dbo_TEMP
    SET [Текст] = replace([Текст],'r',' ')

Comment: перед буквой "r" слеш визуальным редактором подрезался  - подставь

Comment: Тоже нет ( Сейчас ничего не удаляет. У меня поле `nvarchar(255)`, если это о чем-то скажет.

    UPDATE dbo_TEMP
        SET [Текст] = replace([Текст],'\r',' ')

Comment: Из вариантов только попробовать \\n удалить.

Comment: Не помогает \\n, $, :Cc, \\r

Comment: sql-server, а не mysql

Answer (score 0):

Смотрите в этом направлении:

```
REPLACE(ТВОЕ ПОЛЕ, chr(10), '')  REPLACE(ТВОЕ ПОЛЕ, chr(13), '')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE Table SET [text] = REPLACE([text], CHAR(10) + CHAR(13),' ')
```

Таким же образом можно добавлять перевод строки и возврат каретки в результат запроса, если это требуется, аггрегируя результаты работы в курсоре, например.

```
SELECT @res = @res + CHAR(10) + CHAR(13);
```

Answer (score 0):

У меня сработало `replace(replace([текст],char(10),''),char(13),'')`

Comment: Ещё один replace пропустила

Comment: спс, исправлено!

Comment: ага, вижу, исправлено

Comment: Microsoft sql server

Answer (score -1):

replace(replace(ADDRESS,char(13),' '),char(10),' ')

Comment: А пояснения будут?

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: @PavelMayorov, да и так всё понятно же.